# Column not found in SQL laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to publish post with user that register in my app, but this error happened:
 [image]

And I'm using XAMPP and my posts table is this picture
[image]

And this error is in phpMyAdmin:
[image]

My `PostController` is:

```
use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller

{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts=Post::latest()->get();

        return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {

        return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {

       $this->validate(request(),[
           'title'=>'required',
           'body' => 'required|min:5'
       ]);


        Post::create(request([
           'title' => request('title'),
            'body' => request('body'),
            'user_id' =>auth()->id()
            //auth()->user()->id*/
        ]));

        return redirect()->home;
    }
}
```

and Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your store method is wrong.

Try something like this:

```
public function store()
{

   $this->validate(request(),[
       'title'=>'required',
       'body' => 'required|min:5'
   ]);

   Post::create([
       'title' => request('title'),
       'body' => request('body'),
       'user_id' =>auth()->id()
   ]);

    return redirect()->home;

}
```

This code works for you?

Comment: Your code was wrong because you need to transfer an array of information to the create method of the Post. The method needs to know the column => value. Previously, you sended the request itself too. That's all...

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT into posts (title, body, userId) VALUES ('My title', 'My body', 7)
```

The first part specifies the field name, the second part specifies the values you are inserting into each field.  'My title' isn't the field you are inserting info into, it's shown as title.

Also, createdon uses timestamp so you don't need to include that.  Updated on could insert a current timestamp once a record is changed.

Comment: please write complete How Can I fix it

Comment: I'm not sure what data you were trying to insert in your statement above, but it should go into the section after VALUES that is in parentheses above.  The problem appears in how you were naming your fields.  

INSERT into posts (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('Field1 Value', 'Field2 Value', 'Field3 Value')

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    include('../dbcon.php');
    $rolno= $_POST['rollno'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $city= $_POST['city'];
    $pcon= $_POST['pcon'];
    $std= $_POST['std'];
    $imagename= $_FILES['simg'] ['name'];
    $tempname= $_FILES['simg'] ['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempname,"../dataimg/$imagename");

    $qry= "SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `rollno`='$rolno' AND `name`='$name'";
    //$qry="INSERT INTO `student`(`rollno`, `name`, `city`, `pcont`, `standerd`,`image`) VALUES ('$rolno','$name','$city','$pcon','$std','$imagename')";
        echo "$qry";
    $run= mysqli_query($con,$qry);

    if ($run == true)
     {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('Data Inserted Successfully.');
        </script>
        <?php

    }

}
```

?>

Comment: in this program i got the issue

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality